# Backbone Ajax request with array of json data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

I'm making a REST api for NodeJS with MongoDB that's using Backbone on the front end. This is the demo model

```
var MenuItem = Backbone.Model.extend({

    idAttribute: "_id",

    urlRoot: '/sentences'

});
```

This is the view code that calls fetch on that model (note I don't show the creation of that model in this code). I've hardcoded the _id for one of the mongo documents

```
itemDetails: function (event){
    this.menuItemModel.set('_id', '526c0e21977a67d6966dc763');
    this.menuItemModel.fetch();
```

The url that's generated for the post is this when `menuItem.fetch()` is called

```
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:8080/sentences/526c0e21977a67d6966dc763".
```

Below is the json data at `localhost:8080/sentences`, so the xhr request to the url with the Mongo object id returns nothing. If I do `localhost:8080/sentences/1`, however,  it returns the first from the array of json data.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "526c0e21977a67d6966dc763",
    "question": "1",
    "uk": "I heard a bloke on the train say that tomorrow's trains will be delayed.",
    "us": "I heard a guy on the train say that tomorrow's trains will be delayed."
  },
  {
    "_id": "526c0e21977a67d6966dc764",
    "question": "2",
    "uk": "Tom went outside for a fag. I think he smokes too much!",
    "us": "Tom went outside for a cigarette. I think he smokes too much!"
  },
  {
    "_id": "526c0e21977a67d6966dc765",
    "question": "3",
    "uk": "Do you fancy going to the cinema on Friday?",
    "us": "How about going to the movies on Friday"
  }
]
```

Question: Why isn't Backbone automagically returning the record when I call fetch on the model?

Update

this is the node.js method/route in server.js that returns the sentences

```
app.get('/sentences', function (req, res){

     db.collection('english', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {

            res.send(items);

        });
    });

})
```

Update

this is the function that searches for an individual record. It used to search by `question` (at which time `/sentences/1` returned a record) but now that I've changed it to search by _id, this url (with the mongo id) is still not working `"http://localhost:8080/sentences/526c0e21977a67d6966dc763"`

```
app.get('/sentences/:id', function(req,res){


     var query = { '_id' : req.params.id };


    db.collection('english').findOne(query, function(err, doc) {
        if(err) throw err;

        console.dir(doc);
        res.send(doc);


    });


});
```

Comment: So Backbone is making the correct request and the server is returning the correct JSON for that request but nothing shows up inside `this.menuItemModel` after the AJAX request has finished?

Comment: @muistooshort no, this is the request Backbone's making `http://localhost:8080/sentences/526c0e21977a67d6966dc763` however, that doesn't return anything, either through backbone or if I put that url in the browser directly.  The server is only returning JSON if I manually enter the following urls in the browser, `localhost:8080/sentences` or `localhost:8080/sentences/1`or `localhost:8080/sentences/2` or `localhost:8080/sentences/3`

Comment: So your server doesn't really use `_id` as the `id` (in the RESTful sense), it uses `question` instead?

Comment: @muistooshort, ok, good point, yes, it uses `question` but I changed it just now to `_id` and `http://localhost:8080/sentences/526c0e21977a67d6966dc763` still don't work . I'll update OP with the find by id `sentences/id` method

Comment: Do you need to `ObjectId(req.params.id)`? You need that sort of nonsense in the MongoDB shell, not sure about the node.js interface. Or if `question` is unique, you could use `idAttribute: 'question'` in the client stuff and query on `{question: req.params.id}` server-side.

Comment: @muistooshort you're right. If I change idAttribute to question, then it works if the server users `question` to search. However, if I have idAttribute set to `_id` (underscore for Mongo) and try to search by id on the server, it's not working, probably because I hard coded the id as a `string` as you seem to suggest might be the problem. Thanks so much.